# Rcpp: Storing elements to subset of vector

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm still wrapping my head around Rcpp logic coming from an R context, so please be patient with me! From the following code:

```
Cjplus <- c(0,0)
Kseq <- c(1,2)
cand <- c(0,1)
cppFunction("NumericVector test(NumericVector Cjplus, NumericVector Kseq,
                   NumericVector cand, int i) {
  NumericVector A = as<NumericVector>(Cjplus[Kseq-1]);
  int B = cand[i-2];
  as<NumericVector>(Cjplus[Kseq-1]) = A + B;
  return Cjplus[Kseq-1];
}")
test(Cjplus, Kseq, cand, 3)
```

I expect to get [1] 1 1 as my output, but instead I get [1] 0 0. Am I indexing incorrectly here?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't do too much at once (in your example subset assignment and addition of a vector and an int with recycling). You also should always `copy` input values if you intent to modify them. Otherwise your function modifies the values passed by reference (in your example `Cjplus`) as a side-effect. And side-effects should be avoided, unless they are intended for performance optimization and carefully managed.

Comment: Well -- to be blunt it doesn't matter "where you come from" but matters is that you come to terms with how compiled and statically linked languages work which is simply different. There are lots of really good C++ books (and the [StackOverflow resource list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) on C++ is _excellent_). Glancing at your code you mistake taking -1 off a value and off a position. Maybe print some more debugging statements (and switch to `sourceCpp()` instead -- easier editing).

Comment: I've added an example for subset-assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you try to use subset-assignment.

```
Cjplus <- c(0,0)
Kseq <- c(1,2)
cand <- c(0,1)

cppFunction("NumericVector test(NumericVector Cjplus, NumericVector Kseq,
                   NumericVector cand, int i) {
  NumericVector A = Cjplus[Kseq-1];
  double B = cand[i-2];
  A = A + B;
  return A;
}")
test(Cjplus, Kseq, cand, 3)
#[1] 1 1
```

Edit:

Here is a version that does subset-assignment.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("NumericVector test(const NumericVector Cjplus, NumericVector Kseq,
                   NumericVector cand, int i) {
  NumericVector C = clone(Cjplus);
  NumericVector A = C[Kseq-1];
  double B = cand[i-2];
  A = A + B;
  C[Kseq-1] = A;
  return C;
}")
test(Cjplus, Kseq, cand, 3)
#[1] 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you for providing both versions! This is really helpful for me to understand how to do what's fairly basic in R in C++